Error in exporting picture from chart in Excel
Why does this VBA-string suddenly stop working in my macro for Excel?
cht.Chart.Export Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & Range("L5")
It has been working for years, but now I get the following error message (translated by me from Swedish):
Runtime error number: '-2147467259 (80004005)'.:
The method 'Export' in the object '_Chart' failed.

An empty .jpg-file with the correct name is created on my desktop.
I guess that the problem is therefore not connected to the string:
Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & Range("L5").
The error must be related to:
cht.Chart.Export which is the command that should create the picture from the chart.
I have tried to run the macro in an old version of the file, in which I know that the function worked. Now it also failed.
I use the latest version of Microsoft 365 in Windows 11.
Has something changed in my environment?

Is the worksheet protected?

No, the worksheet is not protected.

That rules out: Run-time error-2147467259 (80004005) when you set a property of a chart.    I would create a new workbook, add a chart, and try to export it as a picture.  It's possible that the workbook is corrupt.

I have tried to run the macro in an old version of the file, in which I know that the function worked. Now it also failed. It's a big file with several sheets...

I get the same error if the path is not valid.    Double check the path.

I would like to let you know that I found a solution to the problem. The VBA-error occurs in the line:   -  cht.Chart.Export Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop" & Range("L5")  -  but the problem relates to the formatting of the chart in the lines:

cht.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse  -  and  -   cht.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse    -    When I remove these commands, the macro works fine again. I do get a small border line, but there is no problem with the transparency of the chart. Nice pictures are created, and I am happy again.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78959776/error-in-exporting-picture-from-chart-in-excel?noredirect=1#comment139246019_78959776

Your comment that removing some formatting commands prior to exporting the chart tells me that the chart may still be in the process of reformatting when VBA tries the export.
What often helps is inserting one line:
DoEvents

after the formatting and before the exporting. Or sometimes insert this line twice.
Also because of OCD, I would change Range("L5") to ActiveSheet.Range("L5").Value.
